# Build Chrome Extension that receives voice input

Tags: google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition

I plan to build a Chrome Extension that allows users to navigate web pages via voice commands.
To do so, I plan to put my speech recognition program on a backend server that connects with clients via Chrome extension.

Is it possible? I know how to develop an extension, but would appreciate if you could show a way of receiving voice input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify Chrome.

Until the HTML5  tag gets landed in Chrome, your only option right now is to use NPAPI and include the plugin into your Extension. For more information visit this page:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement a JavaScript audio input API using C++ inside Chromium, being aware that you have to transfer data through the sandbox, then once exported you can use the new API in your extension.

A lot of groundwork has already been done on specifying the audio API, read the details over at W3C:

http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/specification/specification.html

Which links to details of a special build of Chrome with some already built samples:

http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html